# Regarding age limits for PR of Australia and NZ

Tags: australia, new-zealand, pr

(1) Can people above 45 years of age apply for Australian PR? I see that you get 0 points if you are above 45 years of age, but does that make me ineligible rightaway?

(2) Can people above 55 years of age apply for New Zealand Skilled Migrant Residence Visa? I can score around 200 points easily due to my 10 years skilled foreign experience (they are currently selecting people with 160 points at least) even though I score 0 points for age (55 years or above gives 0 points). But am I ineligible due to age?

Comment: The regulations provide that an applicant older than 45 (for AUS) or 55 (for NZ) gets -0- points for age. You infer there is no mention of age-related disqualification. Thus, both presentations suggest strongly that candidates older than the stated ages will be considered as applicants, even though they are awarded zero age-related points

Comment: [This](https://www.new-zealand-immigration.com/immigration-points-guide/age/) website and [this](https://www.newzealandnow.govt.nz/move-to-nz/new-zealand-visa/work-visa/skilled-migrant-visas) one mentions that 55 years+ age makes one ineligible. I found them after I posted the question, but I don't know if those sites can be trusted or not as I do not know whether they are official or not.

Comment: Also, for Australia, just making a search ["age limit Australia Skilled Visa"](https://www.google.com/search?q=age+limit+Australia+Skilled+Visa&oq=age+limit+Australia+Skilled+Visa&aqs=chrome..69i57.341j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gives results from so many unofficial websites that say that 45 years+ age makes me ineligible. Can you provide me with something official or trustable?

Comment: My comment was based on the statements you made in your question. The first page you cite now in comments is not a NZ government site; it gives no reference for its assertion that the Skilled Migrant NZ visa is limited to applicants 55 or under, and is therefore (to me) not persuasive. OTOH, the second page you cite is indeed a NZ government page, and says explicitly that the Skilled Migrant NZ visa requires applicants to be 55 or under. This contradicts my first comment, and as a NZ gov site is persuasive. I now think Skilled Migrant NZ applicants must be under 55.

Comment: The Australian Skilled Occupation List (https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/working-in-australia/skill-occupation-list) is long, and includes categories assessed by many different AUS government agencies at the federal and state/provincial level. I see no single page with an age limit, but have not reviewed each possible category. As before, I give more credence to official pages than I do to aftermarket/commercial ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, none of this is intended to be advice and is only meant to point you in the direction of the official sources.

For Australian permanent residency, it will depend on the visa you're after. For example take a look at the [official eligibility criteria for the 189 visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/skilled-independent-189/points-tested#Eligibility)

It says on that page that

> You must be aged under 45 when we invite you to apply for the visa.
>
> You can still apply for the visa if you turn 45 after we invite you to
> apply.
>
> If you turn 45 after you submit your EOI but before we invite you to
> apply, you will not be invited to apply.

Contrast this with the [186 visa age requirements](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/employer-nomination-scheme-186/direct-entry-stream#Eligibility) which say:

> Usually, you must be under 45 years of age when you apply.
>
> You are exempt from this criteria if any of the following applies to
> you:
>
> - you are nominated as an academic (university lecturer or faculty head at Academic Level B, C D or E) by a university in Australia
> - you are nominated as a scientist, researcher or technical (scientific) specialist at ANZSCO skill level 1 or 2 by an Australian
>   scientific government agency
> - you currently hold a Special Category (subclass 444) or New Zealand citizen's family member (subclass 461) visa and have worked for the
>   employer who nominated you, in the nominated position, for at least 2
>   years in the last 3 years immediately before you apply. The 2 years
>   excludes periods of unpaid leave.

Note that Australian visa eligibility criteria are often different for citizens of New Zealand. The [page for the 189 visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/skilled-independent-189/new-zealand#Eligibility) for example makes no mention of age. (Though that may come into play in the sub-requirements listed. Do your own research, obviously.)

Have a look at the [visa list page](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing) on the immigration website.